# Best driver for kannada text

Tags: drivers

When tried to print kannada text by giving command lp at the terminal in Linux pc , ghost letters printed. How to choose right driver for making correct printing of kannada text.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Are you using virtualization, and if so, which package? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our channel to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Also see https://itsfoss.com/type-indian-languages-ubuntu/